# Getting Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in Unit Testing in Angular using Karma Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, socket.io, karma-jasmine

In my component.ts file, I have a service named 'socketService' where I'm using socket and in component, I have the line

```
this.socket = this.socketService.getSocketIOConnector(this.data.product)
this.socket.on('connected', (message: string) => {
    this.connectionMsg = message
})
```

and in my spec.ts file, I have

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OndemandComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));
it("should check socket service", inject([SocketioService], (socketioService: SocketioService) => {
  socketioService = TestBed.get(SocketioService);
  const spy = spyOn(socketioService, "getSocketIOConnector");
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
it("should create", () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

It is giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined while testing near this.socket.on in component.

Comment: Hi! First of all, can you put the whole code? Are you defined component.data.product property?
Later, if you use inject() method you don't need to use TestBed.get(). Both of them should be the same instance. So I recomend you use only one. Also, you can use TestBed.inject() method instead `socketioService = TestBed.inject(SocketioService);`
Hope it helps.

Comment: @lorenago Thanks for pointing it out. That was my mistake, I forgot to remove the TetBed. But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Please show us how you call `TestBed.configureTestingModule(..)`.

Comment: Where did you call `this.socket.on`, `constructor` or `ngOnInit`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 calling it inside ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mock the return value of `getSocketIOConnector` method. That's why you got the error. Besides, you need to call `fixture.detectChanges();` after the mock to trigger the `ngOnInit` method of the component.

Here is a working example using `angular` v11+:

`ondemand.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';

@Component({})
export class OndemandComponent implements OnInit {
  socket: SocketService;
  data = {
    product: 'real product',
  };
  connectionMsg: string;
  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket = this.socketService.getSocketIOConnector(this.data.product);
    this.socket.on('connected', (message: string) => {
      this.connectionMsg = message;
    });
  }
}
```

`socket.service.ts`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  getSocketIOConnector(params) {
    return this;
  }
  on(event, listener) {}
}
```

`ondemand.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { OndemandComponent } from './ondemand.component';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';

fdescribe('65302152', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OndemandComponent>;
  let component: OndemandComponent;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OndemandComponent],
      providers: [SocketService],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OndemandComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check socket service', inject(
    [SocketService],
    (socketioService: SocketService) => {
      const connectorSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('connector', ['on']);
      connectorSpy.on.and.callFake((event, listener) => {
        listener('fake message');
      });
      const getSocketIOConnectorSpy = spyOn(
        socketioService,
        'getSocketIOConnector'
      ).and.returnValue(connectorSpy);

      // trigger ngOnInit of component
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(getSocketIOConnectorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith('real product');
      expect(connectorSpy.on).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(
        'connected',
        jasmine.any(Function)
      );
    }
  ));
});
```

unit test result:

[image]